# In Python, is it a good practice to import all attributes with a wildcard?

Tags: python

and why?

Sometimes I need import all the attributes of a module so I use wildcard importing, but one of my Vim scripts(using flake8 as its syntax checker) always gives me an warning and tell me unable to detect undefined names.

Is there any other disadvantages of using wildcard importing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to use `from module import *`. Wildcard importing leads to namespace pollution; you imported more names than you need and if you accidentally refer to an imported name you may not get the NameError you wanted.

Also, if a future version of the library added additional names, you could end up *masking other names*, leading to stranger bugs still:

```
from foo import bar
from spam import *
```

If you upgrade `spam` and it now includes a `spam.bar` it'll replace the `foo.bar` import in the line above.

Comment: Namespace pollution is definitely the best answer!

Answer (score 3):

Using the wildcard import can cause subtle bugs:

### foo.py

```
import sys
os = sys # just for the fun of it... :-D
```

### python console

```
>>> import os
>>> from foo import *
>>> os.path.join('p1', 'p2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'
```

This is especially important when updating library versions. They might or might not add new variables and break your code in horrible ways.

If you really want to use the `*` import always place it first so that other imports and definitions take precedence.

Answer (score 2):

Good answers so far, but always nice to refer to the [PyDocs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package):

> Although certain modules are designed to export only names that follow certain patterns when you use import *, it is still considered bad practise in production code.

Comment: Unfortunately, this quote doesn't tell you *why* it is a bad practise.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626751/748858) correctly addresses the issue of namespace polution, but I don't think any of the answers here have yet correctly addressed what I consider to be the biggest problem ... It's not *explicit*.

Consider a hypothetical module:

```
#foo.py
from bar import *
from baz import *
from qux import *

def breakfast(x):
    with corn_beef_hash(x) as yummy:
        for egg in yummy:
            yield ham(egg.scrambled)
```

Now a few months later, you can't seem to remember what `corn_beef_hash` actually *does* so you go to look at the documentation -- except that you can't remember whether `corn_beef_hash` was part of `bar` or `baz` or `qux`.  This makes it harder to track down.  Also, if you know where the function was originally defined, that gives you some hints about what it's supposed to be doing which can make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are, if you import everything using the wildcard you take everything from that package and turn it into an instance in your script, a better way of doing this is to simply import the package:

ex.
    import package

```
package.x
```

this way you won't run into naming issues.